# PFsense : connection between subnets

Tags: networking, firewall, pfsense

My setup:

PFsense, 3 interfaces in use :

- `WAN` : connected to Internet as it should be
- `LAN` : first LAN, interface address `192.168.2.10`
- `OPT1` : second LAN, interface address `192.168.3.10`

On my first LAN, one PC only (PC11)

On my second LAN, an un-managed switch, on that switch, a PC (PC21) and a Wifi AP.

Then one PC (PC22) connected by Wifi to the AP

Both `LAN` and `OPT1` interfaces have same Firewall rules :

| Protocol | Source | Port | Destination | Port | Gateway | Queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IPv4* | LAN net | * | * | * | * | none |
| IPv6* | LAN net | * | * | * | * | none |

and

| Protocol | Source | Port | Destination | Port | Gateway | Queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IPv4* | OPT1 net | * | * | * | * | none |
| IPv6* | OPT1 net | * | * | * | * | none |

all netmasks are `/24`

All PC have proper connection to Internet. They also have IP addresses as expected.

**My Problem :**

PC21 and PC22 can access the AP web interface, but PC11 can not.

PC21 and PC22 can ping PC11, but PC11 can not ping the others.

Where should I look?